# Simple Mod-Rewrite rule - single rule - file exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple mod rewrite rule

```
Options FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hosted/essws/([^/]*)/$ /hosted/essws/?key=$1 [L]
```

I would like this rewrite to activate even if the file or directory exists.

For example:
The URL:

```
http://localhost/hosted/essws/candy-sweets-buffet/
```

Will load:

```
http://localhost/hosted/essws/index.php?key=candy-sweets-buffet
```

Even though the directory /hosted/essws/candy-sweets-buffet/ exists.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By default the URL will be rewritten, even if a directory exists.

Comment: Why does it no work? Try to add slash: RewriteRule ^/hosted/essws/([^/]*)/$ /hosted/essws/?key=$1 [L]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Options FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hosted/essws/([^/]*)/$ /hosted/essws/?key=$1 [L]
```

Look! rewriteRule doesn't care if directory exist or not! it will rewrite the URL!
your problem is simple one that too many others have it! DO NOT put `/` in begining of rewriterule arguments!

```
Options FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hosted/essws/([^/]*)/$ hosted/essws/?key=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a while trying to do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalog/([0-9]+)/?$ catalog.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

In my case, catalog.php exists as a file. By removing MultiViews, existing files are no longer a problem for rewriterules.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalog/([0-9]+)/?$ catalog.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Done!